# Format date and time with Json Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I'm new to JSON Formatter and I need to format a list in gallery view.
I have a date and time field, and I am using the expression "=toLocaleTimeString([$Date])", but the time is being displayed like this 15:05:00 PM, I would like it to display only 15:05 PM without the seconds

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is such an option in JSON Formatter. Alternatively, you can create a **Calculated Column** for such a purpose instead. In your gallery view, display this **Calculated Column** instead of the original Date/Time column.

Formula to use: `=TEXT(Date,"h:mm am/pm")`

This is the 'Calculated Column' details:
[image]

How the gallery view will look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "@currentField",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Reference：https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/date-time-column-displays-seconds-if-i-apply-json/m-p/3726339